# Layout constraints inside NSBox force objects outside box

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode9

I'm having problems putting constraints on objects inside an NSBox.  The top-to-top constraint which I expect to position an object inside the NSBox actually forces it below the NSBox.

To demonstrate:

- I've added a **Box** (NSBox).
- Place a **Check Box Button** (NSButton) inside it
- With the check box selected, Add New Constraint 8 px to the top

This creates a Vertical Space Constraint that is Check.Top to Superview.Top, and I expect it to place the Check inside the NSBox 8 pixels below the top.  However, it gets repositioned 8 px below the box, but hidden from view (because of clipping).

[image: Misplaced NSButton]

The warning is about the NSButton's X position, which I simply haven't set yet.  Adding leading and trailing constraints will make the warning go away, but doesn't fix the main problem, which is the misplacement in the Y position.

Am I doing something wrong here?